# OPERA audio tag creating horrible sound

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, opera

Just updated a website of mine, and suddenly got this veeerry akward sound coming from OPERA browser... I got some html audio tags with mp3 files as sources, and they all work great on Safari, Chrome, Firefox etc...

But it is as if OPERA sped the sound up, and added some grosse static sound behind it... check it out: http://jcradiolibre.fr/?page=podcasts

WARNING: **REDUCE YOUR SOUND TO ABSOLUTE MINIMUM BEFORE PLAYING** !!!!

I have no clue what is up with this, so any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the sample rate and the file being played at the wrong speed.

Not directly related, but if you really only use mp3 files,  you should also add them in ogg format for better browser compatibility, like

```
<audio>
  <source src="your_audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="your_audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```